# How to set a 'easeOutBounce' for a back-to-top button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to set a  `easeOutBounce` for a webpage `back-to-top` button .

I have this code for `.scrollTop` only:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Show or hide the sticky footer button
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
                $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(200);
            }
        });

        // Animate the scroll to top
        $('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 400);
        });
    });
```

Comment: To start with *Easings* are jQuery UI feature. You need to include jQuery UI reference for it.

Comment: @Shaunak D : How to include jQuery UI ?

Comment: @tharindu_DG : Thanks for your edit.